# Filtering query with join is not returning the correct results

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I am trying to filter my query that looks at payments data joining with another table (accounts table) as I want the data filtered by the condition accounts.provider = 'z'. However, the results I'm returned are exact multiples of the real figures (times 13, 20 etc) - different dates are a different multiple. The query is also really slow, so looking for advice to make it run quicker too.

```
SELECT 
distinct on (t.day) t.day as day, 
coalesce(collected_payments,0) 
from 
(   SELECT day::date
   FROM    generate_series(timestamp '2017-03-13', current_date + interval '1 week', interval  '1 day') day
   ) d
left JOIN (
   SELECT date_trunc('day', t.payment_date)::date AS day,
        sum(case when t.payment_amount > 0
    and t.description not ilike '%credit%'
    and t.state = 'success'
    then t.payment_amount end) as collected_payments
    FROM   payments t 
    inner join payments p on p.payment_date = date_trunc('day', t.payment_date)::date 
    inner join accounts on accounts.id = p.account_id and accounts.provider = 'z'
    where date_trunc('day', t.payment_date)::date <= current_date + interval '1 week'
    and date_trunc('day', t.payment_date)::date >= current_date - interval'1 months'
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) t  USING (day) 
   

ORDER  BY day desc
```

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: Looks to me you join payments with paymewnts over trunc(date), that can't be good. Two payments on one day make 4 records, from which some are not counted because of the case.